# DataTables warning: table id = table - Ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using DataTables with a JSON database. When I try to preview my site, this error message comes up in Opera and Chrome. It works in IE, but I have to click "Allow blocked content." It also works when I upload it to my domain.

The error message links here: http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

Not sure how to make my browser allow the script.

Here is my header:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/css/main.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="datatables/media/js/jquery.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/datatables.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sounds like a "same origin policy" issue to me. Your data is on another server as the script? Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. My scripts and data are local. Just attached my header to the original post. The data is a JSON formatted .txt file.

Comment: Uh, that doesn't help much. Just to bring some things in order: jquery should be loaded BEFORE bootstrap.js. Then: What is in style/js/datatables.js? And: Did you follow the debugging hints of your link? What does the console/network panel say?

Comment: And furthermore: How the **** does something work in IE and no other browser??? Normaly it's just the other way round. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have specified LOCALHOST by using any of local web server..  if you are accessing external files for data.
i.e. Wamp, or Xamp.. there are few more too.
... as you said.. it works when you uploaded on website.. its mean you are using external contents being called (ajax).. isn't it.. ?

If so please download and install [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). Its free and easy to install.

Comment: This was it. I needed to run my site through a webserver. Thanks!